# Unable to enable logs in MySQL - error : Found option without preceding group in config file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.6, ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to enable logs on my MySQL server but with no success.
What I have done :

1) I have created the log file with the right permissions :

```
touch /var/log/mysql/mysql.log   
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

2) I have added the needed change to the `my.cnf` file :

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

My `my.cnf` file is the following :

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

I am unable to restart MySQL and when I try to logging, I have this error :

> error: Found option without preceding group in config file:
>   /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line: 23 Fatal error in defaults handling.
>   Program aborted

What does that mean and how I can fix this ?

I am using **Ubuntu 15.05** with **MySQL 5.6.24-0ubuntu2**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps you should add [mysqld] as a first line of your my.cnf file.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but unfortunately the answer doesn't explain the why.

Comment: @armadadrive You are right. The why is related to the error message: "Found option without preceding group in config file". The [mysqld] tag is the way to declare the group (the name of the program) for which you want to set options.

Comment: This saved me. But why didn't mysql include [mysqld] in my.cnf file

Answer (score 0):

Open my.conf, look for **[mysqld]** under that write the server variable as mentioned below.

```
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
```

Make sure the file has 644 or above permission. Look for mysql error log variable using

**show variables like '%log%';**

Latest mysql is using **log, log-error** variables.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: it has to be there, probably this URL would help. http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configuring-mysql-server-on-ubuntu

Comment: It was missing indeed, after adding it it is now working... I do not understand why it was not here by default.

Comment: good, by i doubt why the actual [mysqld] is missing from your my.cnf

Comment: I installed MySQL yesterday, maybe a new version ?

Comment: i am using latest version, and it has mysqld

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the section [mysqld] correctly set, but this error was caused by **invalid whitespace character** at the begin of the file. It caused failure in parsing the file. Character was inserted there somehow during copying/uploading from windows to linux. I needed to open file by linux file viewer and then delete invalid character and then it worked fine.